# find files matching several patterns in bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, find

I am trying to find all the files in a folder that ends with any of this expressions:

"00.png" or "25.png" or "50.png" or "75.png"

I am using the command

```
find . -type f -name '(*00.png|*25.png|*50.png|*75.png)'
```

with no success, what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regex` option of find command :

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '(.*00\.png|.*25\.png|.*50\.png|.*75\.png)'
```

Comment: This regex will also match `100.png` and `425.png`

Answer (score 3):

Without using any regex you can use:

```sh
find . -name '*[05]0.png' -o -name '*[27]5.png'
```

If you are really keen to use regex then use this `gnu find` command:

```sh
find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*/([05]0|[27]5)\.png$'
```

Comment: Hi Anu, thanks for the answer I have tried you command but is not working for me

Comment: The first solution is missing the initial asterisks.  Try `find . -name '*[05]0.png' -o -name '*[27]5.png'`

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell I was testing in current directory only. I have aded `*` in globs